# Making a Global Audio Clip in Java

Tags: java

I'm working in a Java project where I play music as a main menu theme. I have it setup where I can play it, and I set it to loop. However, I need a way to be able to stop it at any time, presumably when the user leaves the main menu. The three sections commented out at the bottom were my feable attempt to call on a 'global' audio clip that was defined at the top. This will play the music, but it throws an un-initialized error with the else statement. How can I stop my audio within this function so that I can call it from other functions?

```
    void AudioHandler1(String name, boolean play)
    {
        Clip clip;
        if(play)
        {
            try
            {
                clip = AudioSystem.getClip();
                AudioInputStream inputStream = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(new File((name)));
                File file = new File(name);
                inputStream = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(file);
                clip = AudioSystem.getClip();

                clip.open(inputStream);
                clip.loop(Clip.LOOP_CONTINUOUSLY);
                clip.start();
            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {
                System.out.println("Error: Can't locate sound.");
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        else
        {
            //clip = AudioSystem.getClip();
        //  AudioInputStream inputStream = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(new File((name)));
            //clip.stop();
        }
    }
```

Comment: What library do you use, is this android? Doesn't the `Clip` class have a `pause` or `stop` methods?

Comment: This is for Windows. Yes, Clip has a stop method. But as of right now I am only able to say clip.Stop() within the same try method I am calling it from. If I try to do it in the else statement, it says that the clip is un-initialized.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think here lies the problem:

```
else{
    clip = AudioSystem.getClip(); //<-- getclip() initialises a new clip which is not started yet ! 
    AudioInputStream inputStream = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(new File((name)));
    clip.stop(); // <-- your clip hasnt started yet so you cant stop it.
}
```

what you want to do is to save your Clip into a local variable to allow the access from other methods within the class.

```
try
    {
    clip = AudioSystem.getClip();
    this.clip = clip;
    ...
    }

    else
        {
        clip.stop();
        }
```

Furthermore you could create two static methods instead of your if/else systematic.

```
Clip audioClip = null;

public static void startSoundLoop(String name){
    try
        {
        clip = AudioSystem.getClip();
        this.audioClip = clip
        AudioInputStream inputStream = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(new File((name)));
        File file = new File(name);
        inputStream = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(file);
        clip = AudioSystem.getClip();

        clip.open(inputStream);
        clip.loop(Clip.LOOP_CONTINUOUSLY);
        clip.start();
        }
            catch(Exception e)
            {
                System.out.println("Error: Can't locate sound.");
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
}

public static void stopSoundLoop{
    this.clip.stop();
}
```

Notice, that static method can be accessed through a static method call.
You are able to call the methods from anywhere in your programm by calling:

```
    AudioHandler1.startSoundLoop("yourFileNameHere");
    AudioHandler1.stopSoundLoop(); //<-- Throws exception if no clip has been started yet
```

Answer (score 1):

I assume you try to pause by calling AudioHandler1("clip filename", false)?

Your clip variable is a local variable in the scope of the AuditHandler1() method. When you start playing by calling AudioHandler1("clip filename", true), the clip variable is discarded afterwards (though the AudioSystem class has a reference to the instance, method AudioHandler1 doesn't).

You need to move declaration of clip out of the method and add it as a class member.

Comment: No need to apologize, everybody was a newbie once. :)  Your question also contains sufficient information so other newbies might benefit from it too, that is value for SO right there.

Answer (score 0):

Store the reference to clip you're currently playing outside the method as a class variable to be able to invoke something on it later, like:

```
    public class SomeClass {


      private Clip clip;

      void AudioHandler1(String name, boolean play)
        {

            if(play)
            {
                try
                {
                    clip = AudioSystem.getClip();
                    AudioInputStream inputStream = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(new File((name)));
                    File file = new File(name);
                    inputStream = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(file);
                    clip = AudioSystem.getClip();

                    clip.open(inputStream);
                    clip.loop(Clip.LOOP_CONTINUOUSLY);
                    clip.start();
                }
                catch(Exception e)
                {
                    System.out.println("Error: Can't locate sound.");
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            else
            {
                clip.stop();
                //clip = AudioSystem.getClip();
            //  AudioInputStream inputStream = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(new File((name)));
                //clip.stop();
            }
        }
}
```

The problem is that 'try catch' is not a method, it seems that you have more general problem with undestanding java.

If you create and play a Clip, then the Clip instance is the handler, invoking method on other clip object obviously doesn't change the other object. Invoking 'clip = AudioSystem.getClip();' you obviusly create a new clip.