# How to stop running clip

Tags: java

I tried some topics there about it but music won't stop.
My code is and looks fine, but probably I missing something?

```
public void playMusic(String musicLocation) {
        try {
            File musicPath = new File(musicLocation);
            AudioInputStream audioInput = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(musicPath);
            Clip clip = AudioSystem.getClip();
            clip.open(audioInput);
            if (musicPath.exists()&&inGame == true) {
                clip.start();
                clip.loop(Clip.LOOP_CONTINUOUSLY);
            } 
            if (musicPath.exists()&&inGame == false) {
                clip.stop();
            }
            else {
                System.out.println("Cannot find audio file!");
                
            }
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

When games begin, and I click on start, **inGame** value is set up to true and music start playing. When round ends, value **inGame** is set up to false but my code above seems to not work. Code bellow makes clip start "when I press 's' key"

```
if (key == 's' || key == 'S') {
                
                inGame = true;
                playMusic(filepath);
                initGame();

            }
```

Thank you for ideas.
edited: I forgot this `String filepath = "pacmanMusic.wav";`

added due to question:

```
private void death() {
        pacsLeft--;
        
        if(pacsLeft == 0) {
            inGame = false;
            //createFile();
            
        }
        writeScoreToFile();     
        continueLevel();
    }
    
    private void win() {
        N_GHOSTS--;
        if(N_GHOSTS == 0) {
            inGame = false;
            win_intro++;
        }
        
        continueLevelWin();
    }
```

Comment: I would just guess that clip.open() changes the value of the current audio. Have you tried putting `clip.open()` in the if statement `inGame == true`?

Comment: @Daniel yes but the same results :/

Comment: Where is the code for end of round?

Comment: @Daniel added it.. lets say, that both method make end the round and call method to continue another round (after clicking 's' key)

Comment: oh, @ssc327 I ping someone else, ..ps. sry Daniel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that the problem is that you are assuming that AudioSystem.getClip() will return the current Clip, and that you can therefore call stop() on the Clip that you just got from getClip() to stop currently playing audio,

As far as I know, every time that you call getClip(), you get a new clip.

So, if you want to stop a currently playing clip, you're going to have to keep a reference to the Clip when you start it playing. Then, to stop that Clip, you'll have to call stop() on that same Clip instance, not a fresh one.

Comment: Hi thank you for tip.. I tried this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10666827/audioinputstream-does-not-stop "what is probably what you talking about" but didn't solve my problem..did you have any example please ? Could be on the internet too, thank you

Comment: Yes, the example that you referenced is a good one.
I can't think of a better example. Not sure what your issue is, but you need to keep track of what's playing, and stop() the same clip that you started looping. Maybe debug your code to make sure you're doing that?

Comment: So I do it like there https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40301174/making-a-global-audio-clip-in-java.. but after when rounds end, my music wont stop but when I start new round I got two music clip running at the same time. So basically reference to the Clip is okay..but its for me mind-blowing thats not work yet :3

Comment: finally fixed.. reason: method had to to be called again inside "death" method, thanks for effort :)

Comment: just out of curiosity, what is the "death" method?

Comment: Is method which start next level